# ExtJS - Make store generate IDs with numbers only

Tags: javascript, extjs

When a new entry is added to a store in ExtJS 6.2 it automatically creates a new ID with the name of the model and a numeric ID (MODEL-ID) if you didn't specify any field as ID.

Is it possible to make the store generate IDs only containing the number?

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3gk0&view/editor
Instead of `User-1`, `User-2`, `User-3`, only have `1`, `2`, `3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a custom `identifier` setting to the model, see below. This will set the `id` property which is added by default to the `Model` even if you don't list it among fields:

```
Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    identifier: {
        type: 'sequential',
        seed: 1,
        increment: 1
    },
    fields: [{
        name: 'age',
        type: 'int'
    }, {
        name: 'name',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'email',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'phone',
        type: 'string'
    }],
});
```

But keep in mind that these are **phantom identifiers**, meaning only exist on the client. In most cases servers generate real id fields, and clients get these from servers.

Comment: Worked for me by just defining the `identifier` as you showed, didn't have to create the `id` field as the default is called `id`.

Comment: Ok, great! I'll edit the answer that `id` is not necessary.